# User-Defined Aggregate functions in Oracle PIVOT clause

Tags: database, oracle, pivot, aggregate, user-defined

Unable to use user-defined aggregate functions in Oracle PIVOT clause.

I created a user-defined aggregate function called string_agg.
I am able to use it in a simple statement such as...

```
select id, string_agg(value) from
(
    select 'user1' as id, 'BMW' as value,   'CAR'      as type from dual    union
    select 'user1' as id, 'Audi' as value,  'CAR'      as type from dual    union
    select 'user2' as id, 'Honda' as value, 'CAR'      as type from dual    union
    select 'user1' as id, 'Dell' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
    select 'user1' as id, 'Sony' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
    select 'user2' as id, 'HP' as value,    'COMPUTER' as type from dual 
)
group by id, type
```

Results in:

```
ID          TYPE            STRING_AGG(VALUE)
user1       CAR             Audi,BMW
user1       COMPUTER        Dell,Sony
user2       CAR             Honda
user2       COMPUTER        HP
```

However when I try to use the same function in a pivot clause

```
select * from
( 
    select id, type, string_agg(value) as value from
    (
        select 'user1' as id, 'BMW' as value,   'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Audi' as value,  'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user2' as id, 'Honda' as value, 'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Dell' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Sony' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
        select 'user2' as id, 'HP' as value,    'COMPUTER' as type from dual 
    )
    group by id, type
)
PIVOT (string_agg(value) FOR id IN ('user1' user1, 'user2' user2) );
```

I get the following error...

```
ORA-56902: expect aggregate function inside pivot operation
```

***Expected*** result is...

```
TYPE        USER1       USER2
COMPUTER    Dell,Sony   HP       
CAR         Audi,BMW    Honda
```

Comment: "select id, string_agg(value) from table1" will give an ORA-00937 error since you don't have a group by clause.  Can you give us a complete example of some sql with the pivot and your aggregate function in that fails.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Edited original post to provide a detailed example

Comment: It looks like you're using the string_agg function from here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php.  I can't find any reason for this to fail.  Maybe a bug (maybe pivot doesn't work with user defined aggregate functions)?  If you change your 2nd occurrence of string_agg to `max`, it gives the results you want though

Comment: True. I thought of this as well. Just wanted to find out why I cant use a user-defined agg function in PIVOT.

Comment: I did not find any reference to a restriction in the official SQL reference for Oracle 11gR2, but I run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot doesn't have to be over the same aggregate function:

```
select * from
( 
    select id, type, LISTAGG(value) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) as value from
    (
        select 'user1' as id, 'BMW' as value,   'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Audi' as value,  'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user2' as id, 'Honda' as value, 'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Dell' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Sony' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
        select 'user2' as id, 'HP' as value,    'COMPUTER' as type from dual 
    )
    group by id, type
)
PIVOT (max(value) FOR id IN ('user1' user1, 'user2' user2) );
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the same output as his custom string_agg function (but if you change the line containing LISTAGG back to what OP had, it still works...and produces the desired output).

Comment: True. I thought of this as well. Just wanted to find out why I cant use a user-defined agg function in PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying wmsys.wm_concat instead of your user-defined aggregate?

Comment: I should have clarified... the demo is very simple - what I am after is a function where i can pass in a number or a string and it determines if it should calculate the sum or concat